# Mathematical proof and intuitive reasoning for: $\lim \limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\pi t}\sin\frac{\pi t}{\epsilon}=\delta(t)$

Tags: signal-analysis

Please provide the mathematical proof and intuitive reasoning for:

$$\lim \limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\pi t}\sin\frac{\pi t}{\epsilon}=\delta(t)$$
Where $\delta(t)=$Unit impulse function

Intuitive reasoning (what I have gathered):

> If we compare $\sin\frac{\pi t}{\epsilon}$ with $\sin(\omega t)$, then we
>   can see that with decreasing value of $\epsilon$ the waveform $\sin\frac{\pi
>  t}{\epsilon}$ approaches a sine wave of very high frequency.
>
> Along with that, $\frac{1}{\pi t}$ as a multiplicative factor implies
>   that at $t=0$, the function would be infinity and as the value of $t$
>   increases, the amplitude of  $\sin\frac{\pi t}{\epsilon}$ goes on
>   decreasing with the function tending to zero as t tends to infinity.

Is my reasoning correct?

Please help me with the mathematical proof as well.

Thank you :).

Comment: Is Math SE a better place for this question?

Comment: Ok you are right, you want to show that a scaled and stretched **sinc** pulse ( $\text{sinc}(x) = \frac{ \sin(\pi x) }{\pi x} $) would go to an impulse in the limiting case: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \text{sinc}( \frac{t}{\epsilon}) =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \frac{ \sin( \pi \frac{t}{\epsilon}) } { \pi t} $$ would **intuitively** go to an impulse $\delta(t)$.

Comment: @Fat32 Good catch.

Comment: I gave you a very detailed answer to your other question [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44420/lim-limits-a-to-0-frac1au-fracta-frac12-u-fracta-fr). Have you tried to use the same kind of reasoning?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Sir, I understood your reasoning that how the width and the height of the rectangular pulse is $a$ and $\frac{1}{a}$ respectively and how the limiting condition narrows the width of the pulse and increases its height. I also understood your mathematical proof. The only two things I didn't understand was why for a continuous function $f(x)=f(0)+x \cdot f'(0) + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$ holds. And Edit 1, wherein you have mentioned how to verify the identity in question for values of x not equal to zero. Apart from these two, I felt as if I was gliding on butter! Thank you sir,

Comment: for explaining so elaborately...

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Yes sir, I used the same kind of reasoning for intuitive understanding. For, mathematical proof, the term $\frac{1}{\pi t}\sin\frac{\pi t}{\epsilon}$ is not vanishing as the shifted unit step functions did in the previous question. Sir, what do we need to do here? Will integration by parts take us anywhere? Or do we have to employ some other method?